# How many Socket connections can a Silverlight chat server handle?

Tags: silverlight, sockets, chat

How many Socket connections can a server handle by hosting this [Silverlight Chat](http://www.michielpost.nl/PostDetail_7.aspx) ?

I know Silverlight has a limited port range available. Is this a parameter in my ecuation ?

I own a VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There don't seem to be any built-in limitations to Silverlight's socket support. There's a MSDN article about working with sockets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248(VS.95).aspx.